# Cropping NetCDF by NCO

Tags: netcdf, climate

I would like to crop my NetCDF file for a specific location using NCO. However, I am quite lost in the documentation. So far, I've tried this:

```
ncks -v Precipitation_Flux -d lon,-18.751,-7.684314, -d lat,-40.9972,33.696913 C3S_concat.nc C3S_concat_cropped.nc
```

With error:

```
ncks: ERROR parsing hyperslab specification for dimension lon,-18.751,-7.684314,
Stride must be specified (and be a positive integer)
```

Deleting float and negative values didn't help me. And I am not understanding what is the Stride.

Comment: Okey I see that NCO topics are quite intensively discussed in StackOverflow. Should I put it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you received was due to the extra comma in the `-d lon` option. Try this:

```
ncks -v Precipitation_Flux -d lon,-18.751,-7.684314 -d lat,-40.9972,33.696913 C3S_concat.nc C3S_concat_cropped.nc
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! It is running!